# Angular js custom directives and 2 way data binding issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to implement the **use case below using custom directives in angular js.**

Company form that has 3 different sets of address information to be filled in.

1. Company Address
2. Range Address
3. Division address

Need to define an *custom address directive* that can be reused for the above.
Once user specifies required information, the Company object that encapsulates the 3 sets of addresses would be persisted to the back end data store with a web service call.

The relevant code files are uploaded to plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/H8Cmlf?p=info

**Address Directive:**

```
angular.module('address.module')
  .directive('qiAddress', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        qiAddressInfo: '=instance'
      },
      templateUrl: 'address.html'
    };
  });
```

**Address Controller:**

```
angular.module('address.module')
    .controller('address.controller', AddressController);
AddressController.$inject = ['AddressService'];
function AddressController(AddressService){
    var vm = this;
    //vm.qiAddressInfo = AddressService.newAddress();
    vm.cities = AddressService.getCities();
    vm.states = AddressService.getStates();
    vm.countries = AddressService.getCountries();
    vm.postalCodes = AddressService.getPostalCodes();

}
```

**Address Service:**

```
/**
 * 
 */
angular.module('address.module')
    .factory('AddressService', AddressService);
function AddressService($http){

        var cities = [];
        var states = [];
        var countries = [];
        var postalCodes = [];
        function Address(){
            this.name = null;
            this.street = null;
            this.city = null;
            this.state = null;
            this.country = null;
            this.postalCode = null;
        };


        //declare functions for closure
        var service = {
                //Address Object
                newAddress : newAddress,

                //Values to populate various drop downs
                getCities : getCities,
                getStates : getStates,
                getCountries : getCountries,
                getPostalCodes : getPostalCodes,


        };
        return service;

        //function definitions
        function newAddress(){
            return new Address();
        }

        function getCities(){
            //TODO - Get the list of cities from back end vi a web service call
            if (cities === null || cities.length === 0){
                cities = ["Bangalore",
                          "Mumbai",
                          "Chennai",
                          "Hyderabad",
                          "Delhi",
                          "Calcutta"
                          ];

            }
            console.log(cities);
            return cities;
        }

        function getStates(){
            //TODO - Get the list of states from back end vi a web service call
            if (states === null || states.length === 0){
                states = ["Karnataka",
                          "Maharashtra",
                          "Tamil Nadu",
                          "Andhra Pradesh",
                          "Delhi",
                          "West Bengal"
                          ];

            }
            return states;
        }

        function getCountries(){
            //TODO - Get the list of countries from back end vi a web service call
            if (countries === null || countries.length === 0){
                countries = ["India"];

            }
            return countries;
        }

        function getPostalCodes(){
            //TODO - Get the list of postal codes from back end vi a web service call
            if (postalCodes === null || postalCodes.length === 0){
                postalCodes = ['560079',
                               '560078',
                               '560077'
                          ];

            }
            return postalCodes;
        }


};
```

**Address.html:**

```
<div ng-controller="address.controller as vm">

  <!-- <div id="addressContainer" class="container">  -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address.name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="address.name" ng-model="vm.qiAddressInfo.name"
                placeholder="Enter Name"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address.street" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Street</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="address.street" ng-model="vm.qiAddressInfo.street"
                placeholder="Enter Street"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address.city" class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
        <select name="address.city" id="address.city" ng-model="vm.qiAddressInfo.city">
            <option ng-repeat="city in vm.cities" value="{{city}}">{{city}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address.state" class="col-sm-2 control-label">State</label>
        <select name="address.state" id="address.state" ng-model="vm.qiAddressInfo.state">
            <option ng-repeat="state in vm.states" value="{{state}}">{{state}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address.country" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country</label>
        <select name="address.country" id="address.country" ng-model="vm.qiAddressInfo.country">
            <option ng-repeat="country in vm.countries" value="{{country}}">{{country}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address.postalCode" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Postal
            Code</label>
        <select name="address.postalCode" id="address.postalCode" ng-model="vm.qiAddressInfo.postalCode">
            <option ng-repeat="postalCode in vm.postalCodes" value="{{postalCode}}">{{postalCode}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

**company-detail.html**: (relevant section included below. For complete file refer plunker)
....
      
               
                   Company Address

```
            <!--  Range Address -->
           <div class="panel panel-primary">
               <div class="panel-heading">Range Address</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <qi-address instance="vm.company.rangeAddress"></qi-address>
                    </div>
           </div>

            <!-- Division Address -->
           <div class="panel panel-default">
               <div class="panel-heading">Division Address</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <qi-address instance="vm.company.divisionAddress" ng-model="vm.company.divisionAddress"></qi-address>
                    </div>
           </div>
```

**Company controller**:

```
/**
 * 
 */
angular.module('company.detail.module', ['address.module'])
        .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];}])
        .controller('company.detail.controller', CompanyDetailController);

CompanyDetailController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http','AddressService'];
function CompanyDetailController($scope, $http, AddressService){
    var vm = this;

    /* - should we specify these here for placeholder text.. not sure..
    vm.companyCode = 'Enter Company Code';
    vm.companyName = 'Enter Company Name';
    vm.companyPhone = 'Enter Phone';
    vm.companyFax = 'Enter Fax';
    vm.companyECCNumber = 'Enter ECC Number';
    vm.companyTIN = 'Enter TIN';
    vm.companyTINDate = 'Select TIN Date';
    vm.companyCSTNumber = 'Enter CST Number';
    vm.companyCSTDate = 'Select CST Date';*/

    vm.cities = AddressService.getCities();
    vm.states = AddressService.getStates();
    vm.countries = AddressService.getCountries();
    vm.postalCodes = AddressService.getPostalCodes();

    vm.company = {};
    vm.company.companyCode;
    vm.company.companyNm;
    vm.company.companyPhone;
    vm.company.companyFax;
    vm.company.companyEccNbr;
    vm.company.companyTinNbr;
    vm.companyTinDt;
    vm.company.companyCst;
    vm.company.companyCstDt;


    /*
     * Address objects - Instantiate new address objects.
     * The content of this will(should) be set via the directive qi-address-info
     */
    vm.company.companyAddress = AddressService.newAddress();
    vm.company.rangeAddress = AddressService.newAddress();
    vm.company.divisionAddress = AddressService.newAddress();

    //TODO - Move this function to Company Service/Factory
    vm.createCompany = function(company) {
        console.log("JSON REQUEST for creating company: " +angular.toJson(company, true));
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'something appropriate',
          data    : vm.company
        }).then(function(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            console.log("Create: Response returned form web service: " +response);
          }, function (response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
              console.log("Error from web service for Create. Response: " +response);
          });

    };

  };
```

**Company Detail Module:**

```
/**
 * 
 */

var app = angular.module('company.detail.module', ['address.module']);
```

**Issue(s) I am facing:**

> Information specified in the HTML of the directives is not bound to the parent Company Object.

**What I have observed**: when I debug through Chrome (batarang), the model in the innermost scope has the values that the user types in (as expected), but the Company object in the parent scope has null values for Address properties.

I am an ng-noob and a js-noob.

**I would appreciate any advise and direction**

Comment: please simplify your question, just post the relevant code, you don`t need to specify all of it, such as : var app = angular.module('company.detail.module', ['address.module']);

Comment: Noted..Was thinking of modifying my problem statement but found that another person peso_junior below had provided a viable solution.. However I will keep in mind your suggestions going forward should i need to post any questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N8TZ1QWTt3OSRZ9bW7zy?p=preview) for you. The changes were the following:

- removed the addressController.js since it was not used properly and was not needed as separate file and also removed references to it
- introduced new directive controller in the address directive and adapted the html template to correspond to it
- added `pre` tags to print out your model on the parent controller scope to see that the values change properly.

If you have any additional questions, don't hesitate to ask me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. It worked. I have a question. Can you kindly explain the difference between the previous addressController.js and changes you have made to bind to a controller inside a directive? Thanks again for your patience going through my problem and providing a solution. Apologize for the lack of clarity in my problem statement if any.